# Hide plugin menu item

Tags: plugins, dashboard

Is there a way to hide the menu item that plugins add to the control panel menu?  As seen in the picture below, I do not need the "DashCols" link in my main menu, but would like to keep the plugin installed.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a setting called "Undercover mode" to DashCols. In Undercover mode, DashCols will keep running, though the plugin's CP section will be inaccessible/hidden, and layout editing will be disabled for all users – including those having access to the plugin via permission settings.

[Download v. 1.1.4 from GitHub](https://github.com/mmikkel/DashCols-Craft)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a more robust and easy-to-use solution, have a look at the [CPNav](https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav) plugin, which allows you to re-order, rename and hide menu items.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1) Contact the plugin developer and ask them to make it an optional setting.

Option 2) Use a plugin like [this](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) to hide it via CSS.

Option 3) Plugins with a CP panel have a permission in the user group permission settings under 'allow cp access' to allow access to the plugin's cp page. You could turn this off for your user group.

Comment: Option 3) plugins with a CP panel, have a permission in the user permission settings under 'allow cp access' to allow access to the plugin's cp page. You could turn this off for your user group.

Comment: Good one... you should edit the answer. :)

Comment: This is a great answer!  I chose the other one since it solved my immediate problem.